# Unique together only if both values are present

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I have a schema like this

```
const appSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
 email: String,
 appId: {
   type: String,
   required: true
 }
})
```

I have made it unique together with `appUserSchema.index({ email: 1, appId: 1}, { unique: true, sparse: true });`.

What should I do if I want multiple `email` to be empty (anonymous users)? Currently I can have only one entry with `email` empty because of the above constraint.

Comment: Do you want to have multiple empty emails with the same appId?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `partialFilterExpression` option here.([mongo docs](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/index-partial/))

You can create your index as below:

```
appUserSchema.index({ email: 1, appId: 1}, { partialFilterExpression: { email: { $exists: true } }, unique: true});
```

You should remove the sparse option as it is not compatible with partial indexing.
Here it only creates the compound index if email exists.